# Centos 6 soft openfiles 1024?

Tags: centos

Here are the conf files and details, no matter what I did, soft openfiles wont go over 1024.

**CENTOS 6.7 x86_64**

**cat /etc/security/limits.conf**
* soft nproc 65535
* hard nproc 65535
* soft nofile 65535
* hard nofile 65535

**cat /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf**
* soft nproc 65535
* hard nproc 65535
* soft nofile 65535
* hard nofile 65535

root@server [~]# ulimit -n 
65535

**cat /etc/sysctl.conf**
fs.file-max = 65535

**cat /proc/1/limits**
Max open files   1024                 4096

it shows the correct limit when you run ulimit -n but when you check cat /proc/1/limits it shows 1024, all programs on the server stucked with 1024 openfiles limit, they are all running under the root user.

Comment: Can you explain what your outer problem is rather than telling us how you've attempted to solve it? Is there some specific process that needs a higher limit? If so, which process and how is that process being started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits you are changing affect only logged in users as they're implemented by PAM as part of the logging in process. They have no effect on processes started other ways, such as by systemd or init directly.

If you want to change the limit of processes that are started by something other than a user logging in, you need to do it in that process itself. Processes that have root permissions can change their limits however they want.

```
# cat /proc/self/limits  | grep -i open
Max open files            1024                 1024                 files     

# ulimit -Hn 8192
# ulimit -n 8192
# cat /proc/self/limits  | grep -i open
Max open files            8192                 8192                 files     

# ulimit -Hn 65536
# ulimit -n 65536
# cat /proc/self/limits  | grep -i open
Max open files            65536                65536                files
```

Comment: Thank you, I see now. However, is it possible to force all scripts to use system based max open files or do i have to edit scripts and specify limits ?

Comment: There is no "system based max open files", as far as I know. Again, it depends what it is you're trying to do, which you still haven't told us. Whatever launches these scripts either understands limits or doesn't. If it does, tell it to set the limits how you want. If it doesn't, then set the limits before launching the thing that launches these scripts. For example, `systemd` supports `LimitNOFILE`.

Comment: It is the cPanel server system running on the server with the proc id 2001

root      2001 cpsrvd (SSL) - waiting for connections

cat /proc/2001/limits  | grep -i open
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files ---- I guess i need to contact them, I was developing a script under their control panel.

Comment: How is the control panel launched? By `systemd`?

Comment: The interesting thing is, the same control panel with the same version under the CentOS 7 reads the limit from this file /etc/systemd/system.conf and shows what limit sets in the system.conf file. But in centos 6 i couldnt find where it gets the limit. From centos7 i see yes it is lunched by systemd

Comment: I have just found the program.service file and updated it,  with LimitNOFILE= and this fixed the issue. it was strange that it was reading /etc/systemd/system.conf file in centos7 but not in centos6

Answer (score 2):

**Limits.conf and Root**

Using `*` in limits.conf only applies to all users except root.

If you want to set limits on root, you have to specify `root` instead of (or in addition to) `*`.

Example:

```
root soft nproc 65535
root hard nproc 65535
root soft nofile 65535
root hard nofile 65535
```

Or you can change the limit in your script manually as mentioned in another answer.

**Note**

This assumes your application utilizes pam.  If not, you have to set the limit in the script.

Comment: He's already got that part covered. Notice the output of `ulimit -n` in his question? His issue seems to be with processes that weren't created by a user logging in.

Comment: Yup, I have run into this one before.  You have to specify root by name.  This also assumes the application actually utilizes pam.

Comment: Thank you my friend. I did change it to the root and as David said the scripts itself needs to be set with the limit. But thank you for the information.

Comment: Np.  If you have to set it in the script, then the app is not calling pam.

Comment: and if it isn't calling pam, then any changes you would have made in limits.conf would never have been applied.  sigh

Comment: The script is lunched by systemd, in centos7 it reads the limit from /etc/systemd/system.conf but in centos 6.7 there is no such file and the script is the same script with same version on both systems.